# How can I add a page-on-your-website selector on a custom page class? (Silverstripe 3.1)

Tags: silverstripe

I need to insert a page-on-your-website selector on a custom page class, just like it works with a Redirector Page. Below an image of what I'm looking for.

[page-on-your website selector on silverstripe 3.1](http://i2.minus.com/iGVPwShySOjdx.jpg)

How can it be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I get you right... (me thinks your question is a bit vague - hope my answer is not, otherwise just ask on comments :-)

model:

```
private static $has_one = array(
    "RelatedPage" => "SiteTree"
);
```

field:

```
$fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Main", new TreeDropdownField("RelatedPageID","Link","SiteTree"));
```

again if I get you right, you 'll probable ask next, how can I use it in template...

```
$RelatedPage.Link
```